# what will be the Rails association for ..?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am confuse to define the association for the following relations ships.

1.A user can have more then one companies.

2.A comany will have many team members users

3.Team member can have different roles like owners,investors,advisors.

Please let me the association for this.currently i have User and Company model.

Comment: I think you're looking for the `has_many :through` association. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

Answer (score 0):

What if you used:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :companies
  has_many :roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to declare team_members dynamic:
Declare your "roles" static in your role model (diffrent_role)

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :companies
      has_many :roles
    end

    class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      has_many :team_members, :class_name => "User", :finder_sql => 'SELECT u.* FROM users u INNER JOIN roles r ON u.company_id = r.id WHERE r.diffrent_role = "member";'

    end

    class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
    end
```